# Access Form Textbox as Input query to ODBC source returns empty dataset

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, odbc

I have an Access 2010 utility that is designed to query an `Oracle DB via ODBC` connection as Linked Tables.  I created a simple form with two textbox's and a command button.  The command button launches VBA code `"DoCmd.OpenReport"`.

The report query Where clause looks like this:

```
WHERE (((PRODLAW_ITEMLOC.LOCATION)=[Forms]![frm_Qry_ByItem&Loc]![txtLocation]) AND ((PRODLAW_ITEMMAST.ITEM)=[Forms]![frm_Qry_ByItem&Loc]![txtItem]));
```

the values of txtItem and txtLocation are the user supplied values from the form.

This returns an empty dataset as it is now.  If I query a local table, (using a single ODBC query to extract all possible values into a single local table) this method works without any issue other than the 8-10 minutes it takes to refresh the local table.  If I replace the query criteria `"[Forms]![frm_Qry_ByItem&Loc]![txtItem]"` with a simple direct value like `"1234"` (assuming 1234 is a valid item number), it works without issue.

I've tried to explicitly convert the value of the textbox like `"Cstr([Forms]![frm_Qry_ByItem&Loc]![txtItem])"` but it made no difference.  As this is a query, I can't simply create a breakpoint and examine the properties of the variables so I'm left scratching my head.  I've spent hours searching SO and other sites for clues but found nothing related.

Please advise.  Thanks!

mfc

Comment: dump or output the value prior to the query and see what value is coming through.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but have you tried just querying the left or right of the `AND` or replacing it with an `OR` to see if those give a result?  Or try creating a query table and then running the report from that table instead of the form.  Just manually put in the user defined for the moment.

Comment: StaticVoid - I called Me.txtItem from the form in Debug and in the Locals window I inspected the Value property which revealed the same value that I typed into the textbox.  It is type "Variant/String".  (thanks for the reply)

Comment: TKEyi60 - I have several different Reports with their own queries for each condition of textbox when run.  Item only, Location only, both Item and Location and both empty.  For each Report, I have 3 queries; 1. query against the ODBC source 2. query against a local table 3. query with known values hardcoded into the query against the ODBC source. (thanks for the reply)

Comment: how about **trim([Forms]![frm_Qry_ByItem&Loc]![txtItem])** ?

Comment: matzone - Tried it, sorry to report the same results - an empty dataset.  Thanks for the reply!